# Search An HTML Table Using A Column Selector Input And Then Display All The Rows That Are Part Of That Group Based On The Result Row (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to be able to use the column selector to specify which column of the table to search in for the input value (right now it's searching correctly and the selector selects the column correctly but it searches the entire table and I'm unsure how to specify the column to search in).

Then, when the row with that value is retrieved, I want to also display the other rows that have the same FID as the search row. I did not group the rows using multiple tbody tags but instead assigned a class of "gpRep" to the group header row and used this class assignment to do the color-coding and toggling of the FID groups. Thanks.

scripts.js

```
//********************** START FILTER AND SEARCH FUNCTIONS ************************

// allFunds.php: start fundSearchColumn() . . . selects column to search in
function fundSearchColumn(){
    var column = $("#fund_column_selector option:selected").val().toLowerCase();
    return column
}
// end fundSearchColumn()

// // **** not sure how to tell it what column to search in (from function above) ***
// // https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fund_search_term").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#all_funds_table tbody tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text()
            .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});

//********************** END FILTER AND SEARCH FUNCTIONS ************************
```

allFunds.php

```
<!-- start all funds table div-->
<div id="all_funds_table_div">
    <h4>All Funds</h4>

    <!-- column selector for table search -->
    <select id="fund_column_selector" onchange='fundSearchColumn()'>
        <option value="2">LID</option>
        <option value="7">Code</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="fund_search_term" placeholder="search by column"/>
    <button onclick='clearFilters()'>Clear Filters</button>
    <!-- end column selector for table search -->

    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="hidden_columns_label">
        <p id="toggle_rows_label">Toggle Rows <i id="toggle_rows_arrow" class="arrow right"></i></p>
        <p><i id="toggle_columns_arrow" class="arrow right"></i></p>
    </div>

    <?php
        // open connection

        include_once("c_connection.php");

        // query all funds and get reps as of a specific date
        $sql = "select if(rep_date_in is not null and rep_date_out is null, 1, 0) as ng,
            FID, lid, datastream, ric, lipper_permid, isin, code, name,Yahoo, start_date,end_date, rep_date_in, rep_date_out,
            last_aum, rep_aum, yahoo, Ck_date, Ck_person FROM fv_fund 
            order by FID,  ng desc, rep_date_in desc, rep_date_out is null, rep_date_out desc, lid;";
        $result = $connection->query($sql); 
    ?>
    
    <!-- start all funds table -->
    <table id="all_funds_table" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th index=0>ng</th>
                <th index=1>FID</th>
                <th index=2>Lid</th>
                <th index=3>Datastream</th>
                <th index=4>RIC</th>
                <th index=5>Lipper Permid</th>
                <th index=6>ISIN</th>
                <th index=7>Code</th>
                <th index=8>Name</th>
                <th index=9>Yahoo</th>
                <th index=10>Start Date</th>
                <th index=11>End Date</th>
                <th index=12>Rep In</th>
                <th index=13>Rep Out</th>
                <th index=14>Last AUM</th>
                <th index=15>Rep AUM</th>
                <th index=16>Status</th>
                <th index=17>Ck Date</th>
                <th index=18>Ck Person</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php                
                if ($result = $connection->query($sql)) {
                    $odd = false;
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        if ($row['ng'] == 1) {
                            $odd = !$odd;
                        } // end if ($row['ng'] == 1)
            ?>
                        <!-- assign classes of gpRep/collapse to only display rows with ng = 1 and classes of odd/even to color rows by FID -->
                        <tr class="<?php  echo ($row['ng'] == 1) ? "gpRep" : "collapse"; ?> <?php  echo ($odd) ? "odd": "even"; ?>">
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['ng'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="group.php?FID=<?php echo $row['FID']; ?>"><?= $row['FID'] ?></a></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="fund.php?lid=<?php echo $row['lid']; ?>"><?= $row['lid'] ?></a></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['datastream'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['ric'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['lipper_permid'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['isin'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['code'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['yahoo'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['start_date'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['end_date'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['rep_date_in'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['rep_date_out'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['last_aum'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['rep_aum'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['status'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['Ck_date'] ?></td>
                            <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['Ck_person'] ?></td>
                        </tr>                  
            <?php

                    } // end while
                    $result->free();
                } // end if
            
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
                }
                
                $connection->close();
            ?>
            <!-- close connection  -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <!-- end all funds table -->

</div>
<!-- end all funds table div-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up piecing together code from a few different places and figured this out. I also added the functionality of displaying partial search results so that the rows keep getting filtered down until you type the last character. When that happens, all of the rows belonging to the search result's group (i.e. they have the same FID) are displayed. Here is the javascript I used. No change to html.

scripts.js

```
//********************** START FILTER AND SEARCH FUNCTIONS ************************

// allFunds.php: start fundSearchColumn() . . . selects column to search in
function fundSearchColumn(){
    var column = $("#fund_column_selector option:selected").val().toLowerCase();
    return column
}
// end fundSearchColumn()

// start function to search allFunds table by lid or code and display all rows of that group FID
$(document).ready(function() {

    // start $("#fund_search_term").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#fund_search_term").on("keyup", function() {
        
        $("#all_funds_table tbody tr").hide();
        
        var searchValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        // *** start this is needed to display partial matching results
        $("#all_funds_table tbody tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).find('td').eq( fundSearchColumn() ).text()
            .toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1)     
        }); // *** end this is needed to display partial matching results
        
        // start $('#all_funds_table tbody tr').each(function()
        $('#all_funds_table tbody tr').each(function(){

            // start this is needed to get searchFID once an exact match has been found
            if($(this).find('td').eq( fundSearchColumn() ).text().toLowerCase() == searchValue){
                var searchRow = $(this);
                $(this).show();
                var searchFID = searchRow.find('td').eq( 1 ).text().toLowerCase();
            }// end this is needed to get searchFID once an exact match has been found

            // start second loop to display all rows of FID group
            $('#all_funds_table tbody tr').each(function(){
                // start if($(this).find('td').eq( 1 ).text().toLowerCase() == searchFID){
                if($(this).find('td').eq( 1 ).text().toLowerCase() == searchFID){
                    $(this).show();
                } // end if($(this).find('td').eq( 1 ).text().toLowerCase() == searchFID){
            }); // end second loop to display all rows of FID group

        }); // end $('#all_funds_table tbody tr').each(function()

        // start check if search field is empty in order to refresh page
        if (searchValue == ""){
            location.reload();
        } // end check if search field is empty in order to refresh page

    }); // end $("#fund_search_term").on("keyup", function() {
}); // end function to search allFunds table by lid or code and display all rows of that group FID

// allFunds.php: start clearFilters()
function clearFilters(){
    location.reload();
}
// end clearFilters()

//********************** END FILTER AND SEARCH FUNCTIONS ************************
```